# Custom error message not being displayed in a table cell in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, error-messages, slds, table

I have the following piece of code

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.wrapAccountList}" var="arItem" indexVar="index">  
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <lightning:select name="rejectReasonPick" label="" aura:id="rejectrn" value="{!arItem.acc.rejectReason}">
                    </td>
<td>
<button aura:id="addButton" iconName="action:close" alternativeText="Reject" data-index="{!index}" onclick="{!c.actionOnReject}">Reject</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

.......

I have the following code in my jscontroller/helper

```
actionOnRejectHelper : function(component, event, helper) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var whichOne = event.currentTarget.dataset.index;
    console.log(whichOne);

    var wrapperList = component.get("v.wrapAccountList");//Here wrapAccountList is the wrapper list that was being iterated in the component
    var rejectReason = wrapperList[whichOne].acc.rejectReason;
    var accountRequestId = wrapperList[whichOne].acc.Id;

    var rejectren = component.find("rejectrn");
    console.log('rejectren'+rejectren[whichOne].value);
    if(rejectReason == ""){
        rejectren[whichOne].set("v.errors", [{message:"Please enter value"}]);
        console.log('rejectren[whichOne]'+rejectren[whichOne]);
        $A.util.addClass(rejectren[whichOne], 'slds-has-error');//add red border
    }
    else{
       $A.util.removeClass(rejectren[whichOne], "slds-has-error"); // remove red border
       $A.util.addClass(rejectren[whichOne], "hide-error-message"); 

//Rest of the code
       },
```

Here my issue is that

```
$A.util.addClass(rejectren[whichOne], 'slds-has-error');
```

is working and the field is being marked with red highlight.

However, the line above is not working

```
rejectren[whichOne].set("v.errors", [{message:"Please enter value"}]);
```

Error message is not being displayed

Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: Actually standard message will not help me. It has to be a custom. Also the iteration is actually a wrapper and my error message should be on one field of one record in the wrapper depending on condition. I am not sure if validity states can do that @glls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding custom error messages you might need to add either span or div html tags with proper formatting just above your  component.

```
<div aura:id="error" class="slds-hide format-error-text">Show This error</div>
<lightning:select name="rejectReasonPick" label="" aura:id="rejectrn" value="{!arItem.acc.rejectReason}" />
```

Then in your controller you can access the error component and either show or hide it.

```
if(rejectReason == ""){
        //rejectren[whichOne].set("v.errors", [{message:"Please enter value"}]);
        $A.util.addClass(errorDiv[whichOne],"slds-show");
        console.log('rejectren[whichOne]'+rejectren[whichOne]);
        $A.util.addClass(rejectren[whichOne], 'slds-has-error');//add red border
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the `errors` attribute only relates to (and is only documented for) components such as [ui.inputNumber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputNumber.htm).

[lightning:select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm) has some standardised error handling when `required` is set. It is also possible to customise the message using `messageWhenValueMissing`. You should be able to use these.

(Incidentally, [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) uses a `validity` object to present a number of standard errors but I have found no way to set values that results in a custom error message being presented. But I would be happy to be proven wrong about that.)

Comment: I would need a custom message. Is there any other way to add any message here? Does not necessarily have to be a error message, but I have a condition that a custom message needs to be displayed depending on a condition @KeithC

Comment: @Rimii You can set `messageWhenValueMissing="Please enter value"` but I don't think you can inject arbitrary messages for arbitrary validation conditions.